# Neo4J - return a unique relation that aggregates several realtions between the same nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a quite peculiar graph database structure: my nodes can have several relations between each other based on the date. For example "John" can have a relation "talked" with "Jack" with a property date=2016/02/12 and a property length=12 and another relation with the property date=2016/02/23 and a property length=23.

`("John") - [:talked {date:"2016/02/12",legnth:12}] - ("Jack")`

`("John") - [:talked {date:"2016/02/23",legnth:23}] - ("Jack")`

I want to return a relation that would be the sum of the length properties (length=35) and the earliest date:

`("John") - [:talked {date:"2016/02/12",legnth:35}] - ("Jack")`

How can I accomplish this in Cypher?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can. Just match them all and return the aggregates.

```
match (p1:Person {name: 'John'} )-[r:TALKED]-(p2:Person {name: 'Jack'})
return p1
, p2 
, sum(r.length) as total_length
, min(r.date) as first_date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, actually it is very close to what I want to do, except that I don't want to delete the original relations, I just want to return only the aggregated relation for displaying purposes (and not keep it in the database).

Comment: updated answer to reflect what you requested in the update

Comment: Works perfectly to return the rows, thanks a lot Dave! Do you know any trick to make the graphical interface of Neo4J draw this only one relation in addition of the 2 returned nodes?

Comment: To get the graphical UI to render the new relationship you would need to actually create it in the database.

Comment: Yeah, I feared this ;) Thanks for your help Dave!!

Comment: The APOC Procedures library has something that should help you out here: [virtual nodes and relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual_nodes_rels) that will render in the UI for display purposes, but will not exist or persist in the db.

Comment: On usage of the APOC procedure for creating the virtual relationship, you'll need to make sure you end the call of the procedure with `YIELD rel`, and you'll need to return `rel` to have it display in the graphical view.